# trying to figure out how to make site scroll

Tags: html, css

I know there should a mistake in my CSS but I can't figure out which one has caused of the footer be in front of the calendar.

The calendar is in the lab content div and the footer is outside of that div.

So far I've tried removing `position:fixed` for the footer; then it floats to the top of the page (with `margin-top:auto;` and without it)

I just want to figure out how to enable scrolling only my page.

[image]

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: silver;
}

.imagebox {
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.container {
  width: 97%;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 28px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border: 3px solid;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0.5;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 250px;
  padding-right: 250px;
}

.header1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.header2 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.flex-container {
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  float: inherit;
}

h3 {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.summary {
  flex: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: black;
  order: 2;
  background-color: white;
  top: 150px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.biobox {
  font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", "serif";
  flex: 50%;
  order: 3;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 900px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  bottom: 50px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.lab-content {
  background-color: silver;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: auto;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: black;
}

.summarybox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 190px;
  right: 600px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navtext h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.cal {
  text-align: left;
}

.cal h3 {
  padding: 0 0;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        Tony's Calendar
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="newIt207.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css" type="text/css"/>

 </head>
<body>
 <div class ="container">
    <header>
    <?php
        include('header.php');
    ?>
    </header>
    <div class = "flex-container"> 
        <?php 
            include('menu.ssi');
        ?>
    
        <div class = "lab-content">
        <div class ="input_option">
        <form method = "post" action = "calender.php">
            <input type = "text" name = "name" center>Student name
            <input type = "text" name = "email" center>Email 
            <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
         </div>
         
        <?php

        
        
            date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

            $current_year = date("Y"); 
            
            $current_month = date("m"); 
            $daysinmonth = date("t");
            $d = mktime(0,0,0, $current_month, 1, $current_year);
            $day_of_week = date('w',$d);
            $day_array= array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
            $title = date('F');
            $blank = 0;
            switch ($day_of_week) {
              case 0: $blank = 0; break;
              case 1: $blank = 1; break;
              case 2: $blank = 2; break;
              case 3: $blank = 3; break;
              case 4: $blank = 4; break;
              case 5: $blank = 5; break;
              case 6: $blank = 6; break;
              
                }
            
            echo "<h1><b>" .$title."&nbsp".$current_year."</h1></b>" ;  
            echo "<div class ='table'>";
             
            echo "<div class='table_body'>";
            echo "<div class='table_row'>";
              foreach($day_array as $value)
              {
                  echo "<div class ='table_header_cell'>".$value."</div>";
              }
              echo "</div> </div>";
              
              $day_count = 1;
              echo "<div class='table_body'>";
              echo "<div class='table_row'>";
              
              while ($blank > 0) {
                    echo "<div class='table_cell'></div>";
                    $blank = $blank-1;
                    $day_count++;
                }
                 $day_num = 1;
                while ($day_num <= $daysinmonth) {
                    echo "<div class='table_cell'>$day_num</div>";
                    $day_num++;
                    $day_count++;
                    
                    if ($day_count > 7) {
                    echo "</div></div><div class='table_body'><div class='table_row'>";
                    $day_count = 1;
                }
                }
                 while ($day_count > 1 && $day_count <=7) {
                    echo "<div class='table_cell'></div>";
                    $day_count++;
                }

               echo "</div> </div>";
              echo "</div>";
            ?>
        </div>
         <div>
    <?php 
        include('footer.ssi');
    ?>
 </div>
    </div>

 </div>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This isn't a PHP issue. You should post your HTML with your CSS. We can't really help with a screenshot. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Post the html with your css, we lack the ability to guess what the html structure is

Comment: I added a snippet. As you can see, clicking on Run code snippet does pretty much nothing, since there's no HTML for the CSS to work on. If you add some example HTML with the appropriate classes, it will help people identify what the problem is. If you [edit] your question, there will be a link to edit the snippet. You can then paste/write the HTML in the appropriate box.

Comment: It's not scrolling because you've got everything fixed position, and things with a fixed position don't scroll, and don't cause the document to scroll. Remove `position: fixed` from everything that except that which should not scroll.

Comment: Can you, please, paste HTML with these classes?

Comment: added the html code

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code but, try setting the z-index property in .lab-content and .footer. The z-index for the lab-content element should be higher than the footer element.

```
.lab-content {
  z-index: 2;
}
.footer {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is some info on z-index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: i've just tried that but the footer ended up off screen and I don't know why it isn't scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the last part of your HTML.

```
         <div>
    <?php 
        include('footer.ssi');
    ?>
 </div>
    </div>   <<----

 </div>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

The footer DIV seems to be inside the .flex-container. I have highlighted the offending /div with an arrow. If you move that above the footer DIV it should work and the footer should be actually at the foot of your page. Both the header and footer will still be inside your main container.